# when i compile my sass border-radius mixin it generate duplicate css value

Tags: css, sass

My File structure here.
[image]My Mixin border-radius

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
    -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
       -moz-border-radius: $radius;
        -ms-border-radius: $radius;
            border-radius: $radius;
  }
```

@include into same file

```
.wrapper{
    @include border-radius(5px);
}
```

After compiling it give duplicate result

```
.wrapper {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; }

.wrapper {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

**Why it give duplicate value **

[image]

Comment: The real question is why you're even using a mixin in the first place. -ms-border-radius has **never, ever, ever existed**, and no browser has needed -webkit-border-radius or -moz-border-radius for **years**.

Comment: If i remove -ms-border-radius it but problem not solve.result same as duplicate.

Comment: How do you compile scss to css? Your scss code is correct.

Comment: my root folder then $ sass -w sass/styles.scss:style.css

Comment: Where do you include your code? Maybe something goes wrong there.

Comment: Please check my question i added new file structure image.

Comment: you don't need to create mixin for border-radius. you can just use  border-radius: 5px; directly as it's supported all browsers.

Comment: ok i do that as you say.